# Get changes from main branch to feature branch without merging anything

Tags: git

This is how my repo looks like. I want to get the changes from main branch into the feature branch but without merging. What is the best way to accomplish this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You could rebase the feature branch onto the new main branch. Keep in mind this will rewrite history, so anyone who has the feature branch checked out would have to reset.
(Or rebase main onto feature but rebasing main is rarely a good idea)

Comment: It could be an option but I'm sure there has to be a better and easier method ;)

Comment: You could cherry-pick the commit but that would duplicate it which may bite you later on. I have to ask what's so bad about merging?

Comment: Actually I am OK with merging, I just wanted to know if there is a way to get changes without doing 2 extra commits to feature branch ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is your state and you want m3 in the feature branch:

```
     f1 → f2 → f3
     ↑
m1 → m2 → m3
```

You have two options:

1. Rebase feature branch onto master:

   ```
             f1 → f2 → f3
             ↑
   m1 → m2 → m3
   ```
2. Cherry-pick m3 from master into feature.

   ```
        f1 → f2 → f3 → m3'
        ↑
   m1 → m2 → m3
   ```

The second option results in a duplication of the cherry-picked commit that remains in history even after merging (which absolutely nobody wants):

```
     f1 → f2 → f3 → m3'
     ↑              ↓
m1 → m2 → m3 → merge
```

To prevent that, you have to rebase feature onto master before merging, to let git recognize and remove the duplication:

Rebase prior to merge:

```
          f1 → f2 → f3
          ↑        
m1 → m2 → m3
```

Merge:

```
          f1 → f2 → f3
          ↑         ↓  
m1 → m2 → m3 → merge
```

As you can see, the second option ultimately also entails a rebase, with the difference to the first option that you will have duplicate commits until the rebase prior to merge into master.

The first option never has duplicate commits and the history will at all times show very clearly which changes the feature branch introduces. In my opinion this is a very powerful argument for option 1, since one of the main reasons for using version control is to have an overview of what actually happened. A clean history makes this so much easier.

However, each rebase rewrites the history of the branch. This should not be a problem in most cases if other copies of the repository use `git pull --rebase` to update.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is exactly the reason the merge feature exists.

From the `git-merge` [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> Assume the following history exists and the current branch is
> `master`:
>
> ```
>       A---B---C topic
>      /
> D---E---F---G master
> ```
>
> Then `git merge topic` will replay the changes made on the `topic`
> branch since it diverged from `master` (i.e., `E`) until its current
> commit (`C`) on top of master, and record the result in a new commit
> along with the names of the two parent commits and a log message from
> the user describing the changes.
>
> ```
>       A---B---C topic
>      /         \
> D---E---F---G---H master
> ```

That's exactly what you want, and it does it with a single commit. So I don't know why you want to avoid merging.

In your case, from the feature branch you would do `git merge main`.

Comment: Now I realize that my question is incorrect. Actually I was looking for a way to get only a specific commit from main to feature, not the entire branch. In my case the main branch was pointing to the commit that I wanted to have in feature so I used merging main into feature, as you said =), but if there was one more commit next to top453r, I could use cherry-pick or rebasing the feature branch. Thanks <3